# Created Word Template with Macros, New Files Give "Compiler Error: Object Required" Message

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word, ms-office

I created a Word Doc template with macros enabled. The point of the document is that there is a form to be filled out each day then sent to the rest of the organization as an email. My solution was to have a button in the document that sends the file in an email when pressed.

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim subStartedOutlook As Boolean
    Dim objOutlookApp As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    
    ' Save current document
    ActiveDocument.Save
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Set objOutlookApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
    ' If needed, create a new Outlook Application
        Set objOutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        subStartedOutlook = True
    End If
    
    ' Create a new email message
    Set objMail = objOutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    ' Set the email properties
    With objMail
        .To = "email@example.com;"
        .Subject = "Tie In" ' Email subject
        .Body = "FYI" ' Email body
        
        ' Attach the current document
        .Attachments.Add ActiveDocument.FullName
        
        
        ' Send the email
        .Send ' Use .Display to display before sending
    End With
    ' Close Outlook if opened by the macro
    If subStartedOutlook Then objOutlookApp.Quit
    
    ' Clean up objects
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set objOutlookApp = Nothing
    Set subStartedOutlook = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

When clicking the button in a document created from the template, I get this "Compiler Error: Object Required" message. I'm new to VBA and not exactly sure what to do here as it just points to the line where I declare the Sub.

Also, bonus round: When I can get an email created, the attached file has a strange format where, instead of spaces, this "%20" is between each word.

Any feedback would be extremely helpful. Thank you in advance!

Best,

John

Also, I haven't been able to try much yet. I've been looking through the documentation and I'm starting to wonder if it has to do with the call to the ActiveDocument object.

Comment: `Set subStartedOutlook = Nothing`  you can't use `Set` with a Boolean, only with objects (hence "object expected")

Comment: As for the %20 - are you using SharePoint/OneDrive?  %20 is a URL-encoded space.  If you `Debug.Print ActiveDocument.fullName` what output do you get?

Comment: There is a **huge difference** in Word jargon between document and template. Both are file types but different file types. A .dotm file is a macro-enabled template file. https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm ActiveDocument refers to the file that has the focus at the time the macro is running. ThisDocument refers to the file that contains the code being run.

Comment: Tim, I fixed the boolean issue and it worked! And yes, it's saved to OneDrive...

Charles: Yep! The template is a .dotm so I'm intending to send a .docx when a new file is made from it.